# How to return a video to postman

Tags: java, spring

I'm doing a project of mine something like lets say youtube I've done the uploading videos part but I'm stuck on how can I playback those videos to Postman?

I've tried making the return type MultipartFile class and just returning the file but it doesn't seems to work.

```
@RestController
public class VideoController {
    @PostMapping(value = "/upload")
    public void uploadVideo(@RequestParam("video") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        File newVideo = new File("D:\\test\\" + file.getName() + ".mp4");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newVideo);
        fos.write(bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: By Postman you mean this https://www.getpostman.com/? Why do you think it can play videos?

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj can't it? I've returned images so I though it could do the same with videos.

Comment: `If your API endpoint returns an image, Postman will detect and render it automatically.`. Not a word about videos. https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/responses/#preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Postman support video streaming.  Regardless, in order to stream video your `VideoController` would need to have a `GetMapping`  method that supports [range requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233) which is a non-trivial coding task.

You should take a look at the community project Spring Content.  This project is an abstraction over Storage and provides a range of Storage implementations including the good old Filesystem.  Importantly, it also supports video streaming out of the box as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49356041/5609837) describes.

> NB: Current version of Spring Content is `0.8.0`.